# How to continuously scrape data from the DOM of a page that comes with infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, dom, infinite-scroll, mutation-observers

There is a web page that I would like to scrape some information from.

I start off with gathering a bunch of HTML Elements.

```
var theSearch = document.getElementsByClassName('theID');
```

I then take that HTML Collection and turn it into an array.

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( theSearch );
```

Now comes the tricky part.

I'd like to scroll down the page, and grab new items that have appeared on the page.

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

How does one access the newly inserted DOM nodes? Something like ...

```
var theSearch2 = document.getElementsByClassName('theID');
```

... and casting it into a new array ...

```
var arr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call( theSearch );
```

... and pushing the items from `arr2` to `arr` like ...

```
arr.push(...arr2);
```

And how would one achieve an ongoing process which keeps scraping until no new items are appended into the page's DOM.

Comment: The OP might have a look into [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver). Whenever new items are rendered into the DOM (triggered by the scrolling) the Observers [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#the_callback_function) receives a list of [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) instances which the OP can act upon.

Comment: Additional note ... The OP might think about [querying a node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like e.g. ... `const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.theClassName');` ... and [create an array from it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) via e.g. ... `const arr = Array.from(nodeList);` or [`const arr = [...nodeList];`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: what website is it? There might be a way to deconstruct how the browser interacts with maybe an api to fetch more items. Then you could just recreate that request and fetch all the items directly into an array. Probably a good use case for something like puppeteer too.

Comment: @PeterSeliger The two responses seem so similar, I am not sure which one to give the checkmark to. I guess I should have revealed the site that I was trying to scrape and that is Instagram, specifically the section that is a users "favorited" posts. I honestly don't know how to implement either answer, so I am kind of stuck. DM me if you would like to know more. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisNorman … Since the OP already is in control of accessing the web page‘s DOM and triggering the loading/appending of new content via `window.scrollTo`, the OP needs to pick just either of the provided mutation related parts (registering and handling ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP might have a look into [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver). Whenever new items are rendered into the DOM (triggered by the scrolling) the [observer's `callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#the_callback_function) receives a list of [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) instances which the OP can act upon.

```js
function handleChildlistChanges(mutationList/*, observer*/) {
  mutationList.forEach(mutation => {
    const { type, addedNodes } = mutation;

    if (type === 'childList') {
 
      // one or more children have been added to
      // and/or removed from the tree.

      scrapedContentNodes.push(...addedNodes);

      console.log({ scrapedContentNodes }); 
    }
  });
}
const scrapedContentNodes = [];

const options = {
//attributes: true,
  childList: true,
//subtree: true,
};
const target = document.querySelector('#items');
const observer = new MutationObserver(handleChildlistChanges);

observer.observe(target, options);


// test case ... creating content.

['the quick', 'brown fox', 'jumped over', 'the lazy dog.']
  .reduce((parentNode, content, idx) => {

    const contentNode = document.createElement('p');
    contentNode.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(content)
    );
    setTimeout(
      () => parentNode.appendChild(contentNode),
      600 * idx,
    );
    return parentNode;

  }, target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 70%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="items">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### MutationObserver

The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree.

```
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (addedNode) {
          console.log(addedNode, "@@@"); // your new item
        });
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.getElementById("lists"), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: false
    });
```

#### TRY THIS OUT:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var count = 0;
    function addListItem() {
      console.log("called");
      const ul = document.getElementById("lists");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute("class", "item");
      ul.appendChild(li);
      li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

         count++;
         if(count > 5) {
              myStopFunction()
         }
    }

    myInterval = setInterval(addListItem, 2000);

    function myStopFunction() {
       clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    // HERE IS THE SOLUTION
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (addedNode) {
          console.log(addedNode, "@@@"); // your new item
        });
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.getElementById("lists"), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: false
    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="list-container">
      <ul id="lists">
        <li class="list-item">Rand</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```